# Create a new variable with NA in all column

Tags: r, tibble

I have a *tibble* like this:

```
dat  = tibble(a1 = c(23, NA, 3, 0, NA),
                 a2 = c(NA, 6, 0, 9, NA),
                a3 = c(NA, NA, "censored", "censored", NA),
                a4 = c(NA, "censored", NA, NA, NA))
```

I want to create the new variable called "class" that satisfy criteria below:

- if either a1 or a2 has the number not equal to 0, then class = "yes",
- if *all variables* that start with letter "a" equal to NA, then class = "no",
- other else, class = "censored" (only one of these columns has "censored", then class = "censored")

Answer (score 1):

Tried to create an example using base R only. Not sure if I understood all conditions correctly.

I'm confident there are better solutions possible using `dplyr` or `data.table` but I don't know your preferences.

```
library(tibble)

# create data
dat  = tibble(
  a1 = c(23, NA, 3, 0, NA),
  a2 = c(NA, 6, 0, 9, NA),
  a3 = c(NA, NA, "censored", "censored", NA),
  a4 = c(NA, "censored", NA, NA, NA)
)

# 1. if either a1 or a2 has the number not equal to 0, then class = "yes" ####

dat$class <- ifelse(dat$a1 != 0 | dat$a2 != 0, 'yes', NA)

# 2. if all variables that start with letter "a" equal to NA, then class = "no" ####

# identify names starting with "a" and create a pattern for grepl
names <- names(dat)[grep("^a.*", names(dat))]
pattern <- paste(names, collapse = '|')

# check if all pattern cols are NA and apply "no" to dat$class
# achieved by comparing row sum of NA cols with ncol()
dat$class <-
  ifelse(rowSums(is.na(dat[, grepl(pattern, colnames(dat))])) == ncol(dat[, grepl(pattern, colnames(dat))]), 'no', dat$class)


# 3. other else, class = "censored" (only one of these columns has "censored", then class = "censored") ####

# check if pattern cols contain "censored" and apply "censored" to dat$class
# achieved by checking for row sum > 0 matching the condition of == "censored"

dat$class <-
  ifelse(rowSums(dat[, grepl(pattern, colnames(dat))] == "censored", na.rm = TRUE) > 0,
         "censored",
         dat$class)
```

Accessing the cols starting with "a" could have been done by index `dat[,1:4]` in this example but probably your real data looks different.

### Update

An example based on the solution @NarimeneL gave earlier. Please be aware that the order of `case_when` statements is important here!

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyselect)


# create data
dat  = tibble(
  a1 = c(23, NA, 3, 0, NA),
  a2 = c(NA, 6, 0, 9, NA),
  a3 = c(NA, NA, "censored", "censored", NA),
  a4 = c(NA, "censored", NA, NA, NA)
)


dat2 <- dat %>% select(starts_with("a")) %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(
    rowSums(. == "censored", na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ "censored" ,
    a1 != 0  ~ "Yes ",
    a2 != 0 ~ "Yes",
    rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.) ~ 'no'
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you, kukuk1de, yes, in the real data, the variable is coded in group. Each variable begin with the same prefix. Some thing like this: "a1-age", "a1-height", "a1-weight"...
- Thanks for your code. I am open to both tidyverse and non-tidyverse. I am still learning dplyr and I appreciate if you can suggest another way of using dplyr for learning purpose. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rbui I have updated my answer using a `dplyr` approach. Please also see the help files for `case_when` etc.

Comment: @rbui If you think this answer solved your question please accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by the example data.
If I understand the rules correctly, none of the rows in the example are censored, because always either a1 or a2 is nonzero, except for the last row where all are NA.

```
mutate(dat, class = case_when(
  a1 != 0 | a2 != 0 ~ "yes",
  if_all(starts_with("a"), is.na) ~ "no",
  TRUE ~ "censored"
))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     a1    a2 a3       a4       class
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
1    23    NA NA       NA       yes  
2    NA     6 NA       censored yes  
3     3     0 censored NA       yes  
4     0     9 censored NA       yes  
5    NA    NA NA       NA       no
```

Comment: I was confused too but I think the OP wants the last rule to override the first two. No matter what happens first, if one columns has a value `censored` the the result is `censored`. Maybe we get a comment that can confirm this :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can transform your table on data frame like that :

```
dat = as.data.frame(dat)
```

and then you can create the new variable with conditions :

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyselect)


dat2 = dat %>% select(starts_with("a")) %>%  mutate(
  class = case_when(
    a1 != 0  ~ "Yes ",
    a2 != 0 ~"Yes"    ))
```

Comment: Thanks NarimeneL, the problem here is create "class" variable with 3 categories: "yes", "no", "censored" that meet criteria above. I am struggle with the second criteria which is: all variables that start with letter "a" equal to NA, then class = "no".